# How to evaluate the following integral.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$P(S)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(a^2+c^2+ \lambda ~ b^2)} \delta[S-\sqrt{4b^2+(a-c)^2}] ~da~db~bc.$$

where $\lambda$ is a constant. How to Evaluate above integral ?.

I tried!, but could reach up to mid way only.

On transforming $P(S)$ to the three dimensional the spherical polar co-ordinates using $2b=r \cos \theta, a=r\sin \theta \cos \phi, c= r \sin \theta \sin \phi$ as

$$P(S)= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-r^2 (\lambda (\cos^2 \theta) /4  +\sin^2\theta ( \cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi ) ) } \delta[S-r g(\theta, \phi)]~ r^2dr \sin \theta ~d\theta~ d\phi.$$

Crashing the delta function in above, we get a $\theta, \phi$ integral

$$P(S)= A \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-S^2(\lambda (\cos^2\theta) /4 +\sin^2\theta (\cos^2 \phi+\sin^2 \phi) )/ g^2(\theta, \phi} \frac{S^2}{|g[\theta, \phi)|^3} \sin \theta ~d\theta~ d\phi,$$

Where $$g(\theta,\phi)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta \sin 2 \phi}.$$ and $A$ is evaluated value (I am taking it as a constant) of $r$ integral.

After that, I took help of mathematica to evaluate it numerically.

It would be really a great help If anyone can help me by evaluating integral

Comment: [Identical question also posted on physics.SE.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/378713/how-to-evaluate-the-mentioned-integral)

Comment: @Mike This looks likely to get closed on Physics SE as there's no physics content as such, so it might be best to leave it on Maths SE if it's within the rules here.

Comment: @StephenG I have no problem with that.  I just feel that it's relevant information.

Comment: Use Eq. (7) of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html, and resolve the delta function

Comment: @Mike, Stephen, Removed from Ph SE.

Comment: @Siddhant, I have performed the integration over b by eliminating the delta function and landed up with the following, I tried to do it using polar coordinates, but not succeeding. Please help.          $$P(S)=S e^{- \lambda S^2/4} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ e^{-(1+\frac{\lambda}{4})(a^2+c^2)+ \frac{\lambda}{2} a c}}{\sqrt{S^2-(a-c)^2}} ~da~dc$$

Comment: That's looks good, although the sqrt should be enclosed within | |, otherwise it will throw up some imaginary numbers. At this point you might like to change variables to 2u=a+c and 2v=a-c. Then you will be left with one integral. Let's proceed from there :)

Comment: @SiddhantDas Oh! Yes, I missed the Abs[ ] in the denominator. Okay I do it  using these change of variables.

Comment: @Sachin Is it OK to assume the parameters $S$ and $\lambda$ are real numbers?

Comment: @DavidH Yes, $S$ and $\lambda$ are real numbers.

Comment: @Sachin After toying around with some different ways of writing the integral, I'm starting to be fairly confident your integral has a closed-form expression in terms of elementary functions and the modified Bessel function of the first kind, $I_{0}{(z)}$, where $z$ is some polynomial in $S$ and $\lambda$. Does that make sense in the physical context of the problem?

Comment: @DavidH Yes, you are right, Physically It should be in terms of some elementry functions and $I_0(z)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's deal with the delta function. We will use the delta function identity
$$\delta[f(x)]=\sum_n\frac{\delta(x-x_n)}{|f'(x_n)|},$$
where $x_n$ is a zero of the function $f(x)$ and the sum runs over all zeros. In our case,
$$f(b)=S-\sqrt{4b^2+(a-c)^2},$$
which has two zeros
$$b_{\pm}=\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{S^2-(a-c)^2},$$
and the derivative of $f(b)$ can be worked out easily. Applying the above identity gives
$$\delta\left[S-\sqrt{4b^2+(a-c)^2}\right]=\frac{S}{4|b|}\left(\delta\left(b-b_+\right)+\delta\left(b-b_-\right)\right)$$
Note that the $b-$integral is nonzero only if $b_{\pm}$ are real, which implies $|a-c|\leq S$. Thus, the desired integral now reads
\begin{align}
P(S)&=\frac{S}{4}\iint_{|a-c|\leq S}\kern-2em\mathrm{d}a\,\mathrm{d}c~~e^{-(a^2+c^2)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!\!\!\mathrm{d}b~\frac{e^{-\lambda b^2}}{|b|}\left(\delta\left(b-b_+\right)+\delta\left(b-b_-\right)\right)\\
&=S\,e^{-\frac{\lambda}{4}S^2}\iint_{|a-c|\leq S}\kern-2em\mathrm{d}a\,\mathrm{d}c~~\frac{e^{-(a^2+c^2)+\frac{\lambda}{4}(a-c)^2}}{\sqrt{S^2-(a-c)^2}}
\end{align}
Introducing new variables $x=a-c$ and $y=a+c$, 
$$\mathrm{d}a\,\mathrm{d}c=\left|\frac{\partial(a,c)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y,$$
we have
\begin{align}
P(S)&=\frac{S}{2}e^{-\frac{\lambda}{4}S^2}\iint_{|x|\leq S}\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y~\frac{e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\lambda}{2}\right)x^2}}{\sqrt{S^2-x^2}}\\
&=\frac{S}{2}e^{-\frac{\lambda}{4}S^2}\color{Blue}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!\!\!\mathrm{d}y~e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}}\int_{-S}^{S}\!\!\!\mathrm{d}x~\frac{e^{-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\lambda}{4}\right)x^2}}{\sqrt{S^2-x^2}}\\
&=\frac{S}{2}e^{-\frac{\lambda}{4}S^2}\color{Blue}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot2\int_0^S\!\!\!\mathrm{d}x~\frac{e^{-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\lambda}{4}\right)x^2}}{\sqrt{S^2-x^2}}\\
&=\sqrt{2\pi}S\,e^{-\frac{\lambda}{4}S^2}\int_0^S\!\!\!\mathrm{d}x~\frac{e^{-\Lambda\left(x/S\right)^2}}{\sqrt{S^2-x^2}},\qquad\Lambda\equiv\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\lambda}{4}\right)S^2\\
\end{align}
setting $x=S\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$, we have
\begin{align}
P(S)&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}S\,e^{-\frac{\lambda}{4}S^2}\int_0^{\pi}\!\!\!\mathrm{d}\theta~e^{-\Lambda\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}S\,e^{-\frac{\lambda}{4}S^2-\frac{\Lambda}{2}}\int_0^{\pi}\!\!\!\mathrm{d}\theta~e^{\frac{\Lambda}{2}\cos\theta}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}S\,e^{-\frac{\lambda}{4}S^2-\frac{\Lambda}{2}}\cdot\pi\,I_0\!\left(\frac{\Lambda}{2}\right),
\end{align}
where $I_0(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind (see Eq. (5) of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html). With some further simplifications, we have
$$\boxed{P(S)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi^3}{\!2}}S\exp{\!\left(-\frac{2+\lambda}{8}S^2\right)}\,I_0\!\left(\frac{2-\lambda}{8}S^2\right)}$$
Cheers!